# How to enhance Google Talk to show a message when we are unavailable or add more than one user?

Tags: google, php

I'm using Google Talk on my site to chat online with users.

Is there any method to customize it such as showing a message form when we are unavailable or adding more than one user on it or any other facility?

Comment: Here might be a good place to start: http://code.google.com/apis/talk/

Comment: For customer support you may wish something more dedicated that can still interact with Jabber/Google Talk >> [Olark](http://www.olark.com/)

Comment: I know those commercial application but I would like to have open source example to enhance it .